# java.util.date get milliseconds for y-m-d only

Tags: java, mysql, date

**Situation:** There is an Object *AuditLog*, which contains the variable java.util.Date date. This Object is saved in a mySQL Database.

```
@Entity
public class AuditLog implements Persistable<Long> {
    ...
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    ...
}
```

I am writing some JUnit tests and need to verify that a saved Date equals the actual date. Where `date` is a local Copy of the value actually passed to the `log` Object before it got saved and then loaded again.

```
Assert.assertEquals(date, log.getDate());

Output:
expected:<Wed May 24 15:54:40 CEST 2017> but was:<2017-05-24>
```

So you can see that the date actually is the right one but only **y-m-d**
I then tried this (below) to check if the milliseconds get altered.

```
Assert.assertEquals(date.getTime(), log.getDate().getTime());

Output:
expected:<1495634973799> but was:<1495576800000>
```

Now i think the best way would be to get the Milliseconds for **year** **month** **day** only.

**Question:** Can this be achieved relatively simple and should i do this? I think the Date gets altered because of a *Database operation* of some kind, so adapting the Test is OK right?

Comment: Beware that getting y-m-d of a `Date` object is time zone dependent. You first need to decide for which time zone you want this operation.

Comment: Once you’ve settled on a time zone, this will be much easier and more natural with [the Java 8 date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Consider upgrading.

Comment: Which type does `log.getDate()` return?

Comment: log.getDate returns java.util.date Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "just the day, month, year by using the following code:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Answer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        // parse the date and time
        String input = "Wed May 24 15:54:40 CEST 2017";
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date date = parser.parse(input);

        // parse just the date
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CEST"));

        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

        Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(formattedDate);

        System.out.println(parsedDate);

        // use https://currentmillis.com/ to check the milliseconds figures
        System.out.println("Wed May 24 15:54:40 CEST 2017 in milliseconds \t" + date.getTime());

        System.out.println("Wed May 24 00:00:00 CEST 2017 in milliseconds \t" + parsedDate.getTime());
     }
 }
```

The second SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); parses on the year-month-day.

Use Date.getTime()); to get the milliseconds.

The output is:

```
Wed May 24 15:54:40 CEST 2017 in milliseconds   1495634080000
Wed May 24 00:00:00 CEST 2017 in milliseconds   1495584000000
```

1495584000000 = Wed May 24 2017 00:00:00 (using https://currentmillis.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

- **Using local date :** You can convert util `Date` to `LocalDate` and do `assertEquals` on both the objects. `LocalDate` won't have time, e.g.:

  `Date input = new Date();
  LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
  System.out.println(date);`
- **Using Apache commons' DateUtils:** You can use `truncate` method to set non date fields to zero, e.g.:

  `Date input = new Date();
  Date truncated = DateUtils.truncate(input, Calendar.DATE);
  System.out.println(truncated);`

  [Here's](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.2) the maven dependency for Apache commons library.

Comment: This would be a very nice solution, but `assertEquals` fails because of the different types `java.time.LocalDate<2017-05-24> but was: java.sql.Date<2017-05-24>`.

Comment: You need to convert both the dates to `LocalDate` before calling `assertEquals`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5 - 1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date d = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

this code creates a new java.util.Date with only year, month and day set. result of this example is `1495576800000` which is what you want.

A shorter way would be this:

```
Date d = new Date(0l);
d.setYear(117);
d.setMonth(4);
d.setDate(24);
d.setHours(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should format the two dates:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dt.format(date);
```

Then compare each other.

Comment: This does not work. However `dt.format(date)` returns a String, which then equals `log.getDate().toString`. This is kind of an ugly workaround though

Comment: You will need to format the date from `log.getDate()` the same way (`toString()` won’t work). Is it that ugly? Using `LocalDate` is nicer, I know… :-)